# Accessible, lengthy Terms of Service acceptance

Tags: html, accessibility, section508

A lengthy Terms of Service (TOS) is displayed in a scrolling div so the "Accept Terms" button remains visible beneath it in small viewports.

1. Does the scrolling div violate accessibility conventions, because: 
   a. a sighted user may click the "accept terms" button without reading the entire document, while
   b. a person using a screen reader must hear the entire TOS before accessing the button?
2. Does providing a screen-reader "skip" link somehow invalidate the TOS acceptance?

Imagine https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public in a scrolling div, with an acceptance button visible beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it required to scroll the div to the bottom before the Accept button is activated?

**If the accept button is always activated** then the answer is simple, make sure that the accept button is a valid tab selectable target and is either a button (same page) or link (another page).

Screen Reader users are used to navigating past Terms of Service (ToS) by looking for the next link or button.

**If the accept button is only activated once the div has been scrolled to the bottom** - this is where you may need a minor redesign.

The whole purpose of the scroll to bottom is to 'confirm'** that a user has read the ToS.

Instead have a button that shows the ToS in a (second) modal and locate the close button after all of the text within that modal.

Only activate the Accept button once the close button in the ToS (second) modal has been pressed.

This way you can 'prove' that the terms have been read.

** I put confirm in quotes here here because let's face it nobody actually reads them even if you implement this out-dated practice, they simply just have to scroll a box before ignoring the ToS. If you can make the decision go with the first option of just a link or button to Accept.

Idea: If you want you could use some 'visually hidden' (CSS trick) skip link that says "yeah I don't read Terms of Service but I accept them anyway, take me to the accept button" and jump them to the accept button......no idea if that is legally compliant though :-)

Comment: Graham, thanks. Presently, there is no check in place to ensure the user finished scrolling prior to **confirmation. I share your sentiment that virtually no one actually reads these things... except folks that don't get a skip link and are forced to hear the screenreader recite it, or leave leave the page. The part that I'm hung up on is adding the skip link; to include it feels sort of like saying, "go ahead, we don't care whether you really understand the implications of your actions." Yes, even though that's experientially the equivalent of not viewing the agreement.

Comment: Then don't do the skip link. Make sure the acceptance button is a button / link so it is focusable. Screen Reader users will just tab past your terms if they don't want to listen to them all, just make sure that they can by making the next item focusable.

Comment: My `idea` at the end was tongue-in-cheek, I wasn't actually serious for a business setting, I should perhaps remove it.

Comment: Graham, thanks again. I was hoping to get a few folks to chime in with different use cases, but you've addressed the spirit of the problem - especially with being tongue-in-cheek. No one wants to read 10+ single-spaced pages of litigious blather before they get where they're going. Same story in the mortgage office... the agents are continually going, "here's the gist of this, sign here" - but it's all binding.